# i want to get id from deserializedobject list in xamarin

Tags: json, list, xamarin.forms, json-deserialization, getasync

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("URL");

     if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (result == "[]")
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Invalid", "invalid", "Try Again");
                }
                else
                {
                    var name = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DemoClass>>(result);
      }
}
```

Comment: You may want to pick a look at *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and *[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)*. That being said, welcome on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: You should post your Json and your model

Comment: If your model "DemoClass" is correct and lines up with the JSON object you are receiving, then you can get Id with name.Id;

If you mean anything differently, see comment from @Kanak